# MIP/MIQP Solver for an optimization problem with a logical function and exclusive conditions

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following problem:

```
Maximize: F1(I1) + F2(I2) + F3(I3)

Subject to:
   I1 in [min1, max1] U 0
   I2 in [min2, max2] U 0
   I3 in [min3, max3] U 0
   
   I1 + I2 + I3 <= Constant

   Exclusive condition: When I1 > 0 I2 must be zero and vice-versa.
   An arbitrary number of exclusive conditions may be provided.

Where:
   F1(x) = {
      0.15 x if x in [min1, min1 + 100]
      0.1  x if x in [min1 + 101, min1 + 200]
      0.05 x if x in [min1 + 201, max]
   }

   The ranges and quotients for x are arbitrary and provided as a
   part of the optimization problem.
```

I'm struggling with the exclusive conditions and the logical function, I didn't find any solvers capable of handling such cases.

Is there a solver able to handle such optimization?

P. S. I have a strong impression this is out of MIP/MQP domain at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have three concepts here:

1. Semi-continuous variables
2. Complementarity constraints
3. Piecewise linear functions in the objective

I'll discuss all these below.

The first constraints:

```
 x ∈ [L,U] ∪ {0}
```

are usually described as x being a **semi-continuous variable**. Many solvers have direct support for this. If not you can use a binary variable δ:

```
 δ⋅L ≤ x ≤ δ⋅U
 δ ∈ {0,1}
```

The second constraint

```
 x*y = 0
```

is a non-convex quadratic constraint. This is sometimes called a **complementarity constraint**. Some solvers can handle this directly. We can also use indicator constraints or binary variables. E.g. we can do, using the same binary variables as before:

```
 δ(i)⋅L(i) ≤ x(i) ≤ δ(i)⋅U(i)   # all x(i) are semi-continuous
 δ(1) + δ(2) ≤ 1               # x(1)*x(2) = 0 
 δ(i) ∈ {0,1}
 (Assumed:L(i) > 0 or U(i) < 0).
```

The last thing, (`F1(x)`), is just a **piecewise linear function**. This can be implemented in many ways. Some solvers have special facilities for this. Otherwise, the easiest is to use so-called SOS2 sets. These are supported by many solvers. See e.g.: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/02/piecewise-linear-functions-and.html. A good explanation can be found in: [https://www.amazon.com/Model-Building-Mathematical-Programming-Williams/dp/1118443330](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118443330).

Concluding: with a bit of effort, this can be written in a linear fashion. The precise implementation depends heavily on what modeling tools or solvers are being used. For more information see the documentation of these.

Comment: I'm currently using boolean variables for the semi-continuous parts, but I couldn't express the logical function in any way using CBC solver (via OR Tools). Is it possible to express the F as something linear?

Comment: Yes. That is piecewise linear. Many formulations exist for this. Easiest is to use so-called SOS2 variables. There were designed for this kind of structure.

Comment: Could you please recommend an example of SOS usage? I'm struggling to find some comprehensible example.

Comment: See: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2009/06/gams-piecewise-linear-functions-with.html. This is a bit solver/tool dependent so by all means look at the documentation of your solver for an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is way too specific and I didn't get the idea or even what's happening :(

Comment: More specific is better, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case :D I'm trying to figure out what is "piecewise linear" but the more I look into it the less sense it makes. For example, I'm now googling the "piecewise linear" and found [that](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Piecewise_linear_approximation) and according to the article it is a reverse of what I'm trying to do. The closest thing I've found so far is big-M model, but I didn't wrap my head around it yet to figure out how to express the function this way.

Comment: Start by drawing a picture.

Comment: Unreal. I don't have even a single clue how would that look visually.

Comment: You can't draw a picture of `F1(x)`? You should get your money back from your teachers.

Comment: F1? Looks like I'm missing the point at all. Thank you for the clues, alas it seems that *LP is far out of my reach. It's basically my first encounter with the subject and even basic things require a lot of effort. I'll get back to optimizing my O(n!) solution.

Comment: Thank you for the book recommendation. I've had my Aha! moment and managed to get my model working even with a simple CBC solver via OR Tools w/o any advanced features.